# SonarQube API Docs for custom rules

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am creating custom rules for SonarQube scanner, following the [SonarCustomRules documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101). I cannot find the docs for the API on the Sonar site.

The documentation mentions the 'semantic API' and links to the source code. Where can I find the corresponding API docs?

Comment: Consider [opening a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube) if you have suggestions about the docs.

Comment: So... a likely not-insignificant percentage of developers work in a corporate or 'enterprise' environment where signing into Google isn't allowed for various reasons. If there is an alternative location to post such comments, I'd gladly participate. As it is.. as long as I need to sign in to the Google I can't do so while at work..

Comment: Google Groups double as mailing lists, in case your corporate policy forbids signing in to Google services. There's always a way.

Comment: @mithfindel - I did not know... now I do. Will attend to it.

Comment: as a follow up, to sub to a Google forum as a mailing list, use the following command: https://groups.google.com/group/<name_of_forum/boxsubscribe?email=<your_email>  - paste this into your browser (works in Chrome, haven't tried others);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official javadoc for these packages.

You could either open the package in an IDE of your choice and use it to see outlines of those classes, or generate the html javadoc like this in your command line:

```
git clone git@github.com:SonarSource/sonar-java.git
cd sonar-java
git checkout 4.14.0.11784
mvn clean install javadoc:javadoc
# your javadoc should now be located in java-frontend/target/site/apidocs/org/sonar/plugins/java/api/semantic/package-summary.html
```

(Btw: I did this for you, feel free to [download it](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwlXJfE8u0NPV1hIcUFlalZjMDA))

There actually *is* an inofficial online html javadoc, but it is very [outdated](http://javadox.com/org.sonarsource.java/java-squid/3.7/org/sonar/plugins/java/api/semantic/package-summary.html) and I would not recommend to use that one.

Comment: at the risk of being in violation of community best practices/standards by posting a comment with "thanks" etc., I want to mention that I very much appreciate you doing that for me. You rock.